# How to make a loading animation in Console Application written in JavaScript or NodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to make a loading animation in Console Application written in JavaScript or NodeJs?

Example animation or other animation.

```
1. --
2. \
3. |
4. /
5. --
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Not really possible in browser console. In Node.js:

```
var twirlTimer = (function() {
  var P = ["\\", "|", "/", "-"];
  var x = 0;
  return setInterval(function() {
    process.stdout.write("\r" + P[x++]);
    x &= 3;
  }, 250);
})();
```

Comment: Wow, that `x &= 3;` line is mystical. I would have written `x = x % P.length;` there (using the modulo operator instead of the and operator). That way, the code will also work if you add an element to P. In that case, `x &= 4;` or `x &= P.length;` will not work.

Comment: >... or x &= P.length; will not work

Why not? That just came to my mind as well

Comment: @MatthisKohli: The `&` thing can only work when there is `2^k` elements for some natural `k`, since it relies on [bit operation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators). I wrote it that way because I knew there could only be 4 elements here; Joost is correct that more generally one would use `%`.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it in the browser console as well:

```
var loading = (function() {
  var h = ['|', '/', '-', '\\'];
  var i = 0;

  return setInterval(() => {
    i = (i > 3) ? 0 : i;
    console.clear();
    console.log(h[i]);
    i++;
  }, 300);
})();

// clearInterval(loading) to stop it.
```

Answer (score 7):

The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds) at each 250 ms the value in the p array is printed on the console. The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds. setInterval is used as a loop here. Using the clearInterval, the loop is breaked after 5000 ms using setTimeout.

```
const P = ['\\', '|', '/', '-'];
let x = 0;
const loader = setInterval(() => {
  process.stdout.write(`\r${P[x++]}`);
  x %= P.length;
}, 250);

setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(loader);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this package:

https://github.com/ErAz7/Termination

it supports

- **promise based tranition**
- **easing transition functions**
- **looped transition**
- **frame rate control**
- **playback speed control**
- **canvas size options**
- **colors**

and some other useful features to create animations on terminal like a piece of cake!