# How to show progress icons in terminal programs like seen here?

Tags: node.js, unicode, command-line

I want to write a command-line program that will show UNICODE characters that will "animate" in the left side of a line. How can I do it using node.js to have the checkmark and UNICODE animation you see here in the following image? What are the characters, and how do I make the instructions to overwrite the first character on the line?

[image: Example of the icons]

Comment: Looks like Braille! I know of a TUI framework that uses these: https://github.com/charmbracelet/bubbles#spinner (but that's in Go, not Node.js).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build your own spinner in node by writing to `stdout` like this:

```js
import { stdout } from "process"

function startSpinner() {
    const characters = ['⠋', '⠙', '⠹', '⠸', '⠼', '⠴', '⠦', '⠧', '⠇', '⠏']
    const cursorEsc = {
        hide: '\u001B[?25l',
        show: '\u001B[?25h',
    }
    stdout.write(cursorEsc.hide)

    let i = 0;
    const timer = setInterval(function () {
        stdout.write("\r" + characters[i++]);
        i = i >= characters.length ? 0 : i;
    }, 150);

    return () => {
        clearInterval(timer)
        stdout.write("\r")
        stdout.write(cursorEsc.show)
    }
}
```

Then invoke the function like this - here's an example that runs for 4 seconds and then finishes

```js
const stopSpinner = startSpinner();

setTimeout(() => {
    stopSpinner()
    console.log("done")
},4000)
```

### Further Reading

- [How to make a loading animation in Console Application written in JavaScript or NodeJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34848505/1366033)
- [ANSI Escape Codes](https://gist.github.com/fnky/458719343aabd01cfb17a3a4f7296797)

Answer (score 2):

Use this npm library

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cli-spinners

Implement like this:

```
const cliSpinners = require('cli-spinners');

console.log(cliSpinners.dots);
```